# inter change the images using dragging

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

In my app i want to inter change the images using draging. The following is the screen shot of my activity.In this screen 4 images are there.And i want to inter change the total image.For example when i touch the first image(facebook) and drag the image near to any image example second image(twitter) then inter change the images like first image set to second  place and second  image set to first place.And also inter change the 4 images like the above.And In first place either facebook and twitter image and also second place and also third place and aso fourth place.I set 8 images anywhere in foue places.I done this task.Only my question is how to drag the image and set the image to any three places."when i touch the first image(facebook) and drag the image near to any image example second image(twitter) then inter change the images like first image set to second  place and second  image set to first place".

[image]

I tried a lot for doing this task.This is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

         ivFacebook1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.facebook1);
         ivFacebook2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.facebook2);
         ivFacebook3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.facebook3);
         ivFacebook4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.facebook4);

         ivTwitter1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.twitter1);
         ivTwitter2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.twitter2);
         ivTwitter3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.twitter3);
         ivTwitter4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.twitter4);

ivFacebook1.setOnTouchListener(this);
     ivFacebook2.setOnTouchListener(this);
     ivFacebook3.setOnTouchListener(this);
     ivFacebook4.setOnTouchListener(this);

     ivTwitter1.setOnTouchListener(this);
     ivTwitter2.setOnTouchListener(this);
     ivTwitter3.setOnTouchListener(this);
     ivTwitter4.setOnTouchListener(this);
 }
```

And this is my ontouch:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

        Log.e("id",""+v.getId());

        Log.e("ontouch","workkkkkkk");
        float scale;
        boolean moving = false;//stupid state
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            final int x = (int)event.getX();
            final int y = (int)event.getY();

            Log.e("x,y",""+x+","+y);



            if((layout1.getLeft()<x)&&(x<layout1.getRight())&&((layout1.getTop()<y)&&(y<layout1.getBottom()))) {


                viewnumber=1;
                Log.e("View1","in View1");

             }

            if((layout2.getLeft()<x)&&(x<layout2.getRight())&&((layout2.getTop()<y)&&(y<layout2.getBottom()))){

                viewnumber=2;
                Log.e("View2","in View2");

                 }
            if((layout3.getLeft()<x)&&(x<layout3.getRight())&&((layout3.getTop()<y)&&(y<layout3.getBottom()))){

                viewnumber=3;
                Log.e("View3","in View3");   
                 }

            if((layout4.getLeft()<x)&&(x<layout4.getRight())&&((layout4.getTop()<y)&&(y<layout4.getBottom()))) {

                viewnumber=4;
                Log.e("View4","in View4");   

                 }

            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);

            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true; 

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            Log.e("action move","moveeeeeeeeee");
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            moving = false;
            return true;

        }   
        return true;
    }//ontouch.
```

By using this code four images are dragging fine.when I down the finger and drag the image is working fine. But in between dragging when ever I lift the finger the image will be gone. And the image also not set.

Comment: Can you provide more details ? I cannot see the viewnumber being used anywhere. Also you set the visibility on action_down, try restoring it back using view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); on ACTION_UP

Comment: @AshwiniBhangi that is the answer I was about to type put that in the answer field..

Comment: On action up you have to do some work like deciding which images are to be set correctly or which views are to hidden/shown.

Comment: It is not working,In between draging the image will be gone.how to find out x and y co-ordinates of entire layout.